# How do you change the name of a screensaver on MacOSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, screensaver

I just created a screensaver project in Xcode. How do I change the name as it appears on the screen saver selection dialog in MacOSX. I'm referring to the string bellow the thumbnails, like "Floating", "Flip-up", etc in this screenshot:

[image]

**Note**: I don't want to change the name of the screensavers that were shipped with MacOSX. I want to change the name of my own. The screenshot is there just to illustrate what I mean by name.

Answer (score 2):

This took me a little while to figure out. There should be a file called InfoPlist.strings in your project (create one if not, I suppose), with an entry CFBundleName. This is the string used to generate the title, at least as of OS X 10.11.

Comment: Interesting I get a -1 without any comment. I struggled to change the name of a screensaver project after the fact, having changed every instance I could find of the original name to the desired new name, and it still appeared with the original name in the screensaver pref panel. Until, that is, I changed the CFBundleName string as indicated.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! For me it was also required to restart the preferences application to see the new CFBundleName (when the Screen Saver was installed before).

Comment: Don't worry about the -1. Sometimes people click it by mistake. And sometimes they're just a-holes. :)

Answer (score 1):

The name you use for your screensaver (.saver bundle) will be the title it's represented as when viewed in `System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver`.

**Example:**

In XCode you might have a screensaver project named: `Amazing Things`.

- When you build/compile an `Amazing Things.saver` bundle will be created (similar to an .app)
- The main executable `Amazing Things` resides in `Amazing Things.saver/Contents/MacOS`

Screensaver titles are fetched from the .saver bundle and displayed as such in OS X.

[image]

- (note the title in System Preferences reflects that of which the project was named):

[image]

Comment: No, I'm not referring to those screensavers. I'm referring to the one I built, I was just pointing out what I meant by "name". Which field I wanted to change.

Comment: I must have misunderstood - "I'm referring to Floating, Flip-up, Reflections, Origami, Shifting tiles"; so I'm a little unclear on what you mean. Normally the screensavers show up as the name of the file, for example "Starry Night" in System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver would be named "Starry Night.saver" when viewed in Finder, etc. For the ones you mention though, they are hardcoded into the executable, so changing them would require breaking out the hex editor.

Comment: I'm not trying to change any screensaver that came with macosx. I'm making my own.

Comment: @Pablo, Yes — my answer was edited for your revised question.

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong, at least as of OS X 10.11.